# Combinatorics Question with limitations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

1. $n$ men $\rightarrow n \in N$
2. $n$ women  $\rightarrow n \in N$
3. $n$ childs  $\rightarrow n \in N$

How many ways we can order them:( lets say in row )

1. without limit
2. 1 man and 1 woman can`t sit togather
3. each group sit togather, women, men , childs
4. 2 kids cannot sit togather
5. between 1 man and 1 women there is at least $3n-3$ people

what I did so far is: ( my answers for each question )

1. $(n!)^3$
2. $\binom {n} {n-2} \cdot ((n-1)!)^2 \cdot n!$
3. $(n!)^3\cdot (3!)$

for the two other I would like to get some advice, and for what I answered comments.
thanks!

Comment: If there is another title that will help for other members in the future let me know.

Comment: Look at your answers to (3) and (1). At the moment, you have *more* ways of ordering them with the extra restriction than without restriction. That can't be right :)

Comment: (1) is not correct. You can mix men, women and children when ordering them so... And with this insight, take a look at the other answers too.

Comment: if it were $k$ men, $b$ women,$a$ childs ( $\in N$) how it was? $k!\cdot b! \cdot a!$?

Comment: You should begin saying more clearly what is going on. Apparently $3n$ people are being seated, but there is no indication how. In a row, around a table, in several groups? (I add the latter because of the "sit together" conditions.) Maybe "togather" means just "next to each other"? How do conditions 1. and 3. differ from each other? How can men and women be so far apart (condition 5.) that there are not enough children to fill the gap. There is just too much we have to guess about.

Comment: @OfirAttia I assume you want to put them in a row, right? If the answer were $k!b!a!$, that would mean that you first order the $k$ men, then the $b$ women and finally the $a$ children, without actually "mixing them up". So what you want is to chuck them all together ($k+b+a$) and then order them.

Answer (score 0):

4) First arrange the men and women in a row. We can do that in $(2n)!$ ways. Now we have $2n+1$ positions for the kids , in between each two current people. We have to choose $n$ of them , in ${2n+1}\choose{n}$. So total ways $= (2n!)\cdot {{2n+1}\choose{n}}$.

5) Do you mean that there is atleast 1 man and a woman who satisfy this condition? Please clarify this first.

Comment: yes for the (5) think that there is 1 couple that satisfy it, what about my answer to (1) its wrong? its need to be $(3n!)$?